# How can use ImmutableList<> instead List<> to gain thread safety?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, immutablelist

For example i have this code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Concurrent;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections.Immutable;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lst =new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
        {
            lst.Add(i);
        }

        new Thread(() =>
        {                
            for (int i = 20000001; i < 21000000; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(i);
            }

        }).Start();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            lst.Where(item =>
                  item > 85200 && item < (50000 * (item + 154896556) * 2 / 1000)
              ).ToList();

        }).Start();

        new Thread(() =>
       {
           for (int i = 21000001; i < 22000000; i++)
           {
               lst.Add(i);
           }

       }).Start();
    }
}
}
```

and i get this exception (Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.) because my lst change in a thread and iterate in another thread.
this is my question: how to Rewrite this code by System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList<> instead List<>?

Comment: Think about using ConcurrentBag<T> instead of List<T>. List<T> is not thread safe while ConcurrentBag is.

Comment: What about ImmutaleList?

Answer (score 3):

To gain thread safety, there are a number of Thread-safe collections that you can use:

- BlockingCollection
- ConcurrentDictionary
- ConcurrentQueue
- ConcurrentStack
- ConcurrentBag

You can even implement your own using IProducerConsumerCollection

All documented here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want an ImmutableList<>? To quote the documentation:

> When you add or remove items from an immutable list copy of the original list is made with the items added or removed, and the original list is unchanged.
>
> ...
>
> It returns a new immutable list with the object added, or the current list if it already contains the specified object.

Try instead to wrap any instance where you edit the list in a lock(list){} block, such as:

```
lock(lst) 
{   
  list.Add(i);
}
```

You'll have a (probably very slight) performance hit when your code tries to read from the List<> but it's locked for editing, but it should be thread safe.

Comment: I prefer to don't use lock in my code becase my code is very complex and contains many shared lists and many threads that are working together.
Actually i did that and i face dead lock and very complex problems.
but i heard about ImmutableList and i think this is maybe my correct approach.

Comment: @S.Cheginy: If the problem is that the code is complex and lots of memory is shared across lots of threads, the solution is **not** to abandon locks. The solution is to make the program simpler, make it use fewer threads, share less memory across threads, and use more locks. Shared-memory multithreading is hard. Consider a task-based approach instead; let the TPL manage the threads for you.

Comment: Immutable lists do not avoid the need for a lock.  Two simultaneous calls to `MyList=MyList.add(NewElement)` may only add one element.  That doesn't corrupt your list, but your program state is now inconsistent.  And when you try to fix such errors (e.g., by detecting them), the compiler tends to fight you; it's perfectly OK for it to "lie" to you about what is going on, so long as such lies are undetectable in single-threaded programs.  You can try to prevent such lies by introducing a memory barrier.  However, that still leaves other problems (as a non-expert, I don't know what they are).